# Ретаргетинг сайта по странам и роботы ПС Яндекса и Гугла как реализовать?

Tags: php, seo, геолокация, useragent, geo

На сайте 3 страницы

1. site.ru
2. site.ru/ru/
3. site.ru/en/

При заходе на первую страницу идет определение страны пользователя и перенаправление в зависимости от местоположения таким образом:
На главной странице в самом верху прописан код

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php'); //The above code
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "RU") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "US") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/en/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "UA") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "KG") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "UZ") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/en/');
}
?>
```

Вот содержимое файла config.php

```
<?php
   class geoPlugin {
    var $host = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip={IP}&base_currency={CURRENCY}&lang={LANG}';
    var $currency = 'USD';      
    var $lang = 'en';    
    var $ip = null;
    var $city = null;
    var $region = null;
    var $regionCode = null;
    var $regionName = null;
    var $dmaCode = null;
    var $countryCode = null;
    var $countryName = null;
    var $inEU = null;
    var $euVATrate = false;
    var $continentCode = null;
    var $continentName = null;
    var $latitude = null;
    var $longitude = null;
    var $locationAccuracyRadius = null;
    var $timezone = null;
    var $currencyCode = null;
    var $currencySymbol = null;
    var $currencyConverter = null;      
    function __construct() {    
    }
    
    function locate($ip = null) {           
        global $_SERVER;            
        if ( is_null( $ip ) ) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }           
        $host = str_replace( '{IP}', $ip, $this->host );
        $host = str_replace( '{CURRENCY}', $this->currency, $host );
        $host = str_replace( '{LANG}', $this->lang, $host );            
        $data = array();            
        $response = $this->fetch($host);            
        $data = unserialize($response);         
        //set the geoPlugin vars
        $this->ip = $ip;
        $this->city = $data['geoplugin_city'];
        $this->region = $data['geoplugin_region'];
        $this->regionCode = $data['geoplugin_regionCode'];
        $this->regionName = $data['geoplugin_regionName'];
        $this->dmaCode = $data['geoplugin_dmaCode'];
        $this->countryCode = $data['geoplugin_countryCode'];
        $this->countryName = $data['geoplugin_countryName'];
        $this->inEU = $data['geoplugin_inEU'];
        $this->euVATrate = $data['euVATrate'];
        $this->continentCode = $data['geoplugin_continentCode'];
        $this->continentName = $data['geoplugin_continentName'];
        $this->latitude = $data['geoplugin_latitude'];
        $this->longitude = $data['geoplugin_longitude'];
        $this->locationAccuracyRadius = $data['geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius'];
        $this->timezone = $data['geoplugin_timezone'];
        $this->currencyCode = $data['geoplugin_currencyCode'];
        $this->currencySymbol = $data['geoplugin_currencySymbol'];
        $this->currencyConverter = $data['geoplugin_currencyConverter'];            
    }       
    function fetch($host) {    
        if ( function_exists('curl_init') ) {                           
            //use cURL to fetch data
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'geoPlugin PHP Class v1.1');
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);               
        } else if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {              
            //fall back to fopen()
            $response = file_get_contents($host, 'r');              
        } else {    
            trigger_error ('geoPlugin class Error: Cannot retrieve data. Either compile PHP with cURL support or enable allow_url_fopen in php.ini ', E_USER_ERROR);
            return;         
        }           
        return $response;
    }       
    function convert($amount, $float=2, $symbol=true) {         
        //easily convert amounts to geolocated currency.
        if ( !is_numeric($this->currencyConverter) || $this->currencyConverter == 0 ) {
            trigger_error('geoPlugin class Notice: currencyConverter has no value.', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return $amount;
        }
        if ( !is_numeric($amount) ) {
            trigger_error ('geoPlugin class Warning: The amount passed to geoPlugin::convert is not numeric.', E_USER_WARNING);
            return $amount;
        }
        if ( $symbol === true ) {
            return $this->currencySymbol . round( ($amount * $this->currencyConverter), $float );
        } else {
            return round( ($amount * $this->currencyConverter), $float );
        }
    }       
    function nearby($radius=10, $limit=null) {    
        if ( !is_numeric($this->latitude) || !is_numeric($this->longitude) ) {
            trigger_error ('geoPlugin class Warning: Incorrect latitude or longitude values.', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return array( array() );
        }           
        $host = "http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/nearby.gp?lat=" . $this->latitude . "&long=" . $this->longitude . "&radius={$radius}";         
        if ( is_numeric($limit) )
            $host .= "&limit={$limit}";             
        return unserialize( $this->fetch($host) );    
    }       
}    
?>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `робот Гугла` получает английскую версию сайта, а основная у меня русская. `Робот Гула` имеет американский `IP`. Возможно ли как то написать условие через ЮзерАгент чтоб робот Гугла и Яндекса всегда получали русскую версию сайта?

Вот что пишет поддержка Яндекса:

> Отмечу только, что наши индексирующие роботы могут обращаться из
> разных страниц, поэтому вам стоит убедиться, что на их запросы
> постоянно выполняется одинаковый редирект, даже если робот обратился,
> например, с американского IP. О том, как проверить, что робот
> принадлежит Яндексу, вы можете прочитать на странице [нашей Справки](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/managing-redirects.html).
> [И справки по useragent](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/check-yandex-robots.html#check-yandex-robots)

.

Вот так правильно?

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php'); //The above code
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "RU") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "US") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/en/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "UA") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "KG") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "UZ") {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
}
else {
header('Location: https://www.site.ru/en/');
}
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        $options = array(
            'YandexBot', 'YandexAccessibilityBot', 'YandexMobileBot','YandexDirectDyn',
            'YandexScreenshotBot', 'YandexImages', 'YandexVideo', 'YandexVideoParser',
            'YandexMedia', 'YandexBlogs', 'YandexFavicons', 'YandexWebmaster',
            'YandexPagechecker', 'YandexImageResizer','YandexAdNet', 'YandexDirect',
            'YaDirectFetcher', 'YandexCalendar', 'YandexSitelinks', 'YandexMetrika',
            'YandexNews', 'YandexNewslinks', 'YandexCatalog', 'YandexAntivirus',
            'YandexMarket', 'YandexVertis', 'YandexForDomain', 'YandexSpravBot',
            'YandexSearchShop', 'YandexMedianaBot', 'YandexOntoDB', 'YandexOntoDBAPI',
            'Googlebot', 'Googlebot-Image', 'Mediapartners-Google', 'AdsBot-Google',
            'Mail.RU_Bot', 'bingbot', 'Accoona', 'ia_archiver', 'Ask Jeeves',
            'OmniExplorer_Bot', 'W3C_Validator', 'WebAlta', 'YahooFeedSeeker', 'Yahoo!',
            'Ezooms', '', 'Tourlentabot', 'MJ12bot', 'AhrefsBot', 'SearchBot', 'SiteStatus',
            'Nigma.ru', 'Baiduspider', 'Statsbot', 'SISTRIX', 'AcoonBot', 'findlinks',
            'proximic', 'OpenindexSpider','statdom.ru', 'Exabot', 'Spider', 'SeznamBot',
            'oBot', 'C-T bot', 'Updownerbot', 'Snoopy', 'heritrix', 'Yeti',
            'DomainVader', 'DCPbot', 'PaperLiBot'
        );
        header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');}
?>
```

Спасибо Всем, кто принимал участие. Победитель **Mr.AntonDer**. Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: а на accept-language вы не хотите ориентироваться? если клиент запрашивает русский, то какая разница, в США он находится или Зимбабве?

Comment: @teran мне необходимо насильно отдавать роботам гугла и Яндекса русские версии.

Comment: ну так при чем тут тогда вообще IP ? определите, что там в юзер агенте есть `bot` да отдавайте русскую

Comment: Определение страны для пользователя я от этого не отказывался, а как вот с ботами делать не понимаю

Comment: @teran Вот так правильно написал в вопросе?

Comment: для конкретно вашего кода проверку `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {` перенесите в начало файла, до того как вызываете `new geoPlugin();`

Comment: @teran судя по логам бот перешел не английскую версию сайта

Comment: Вначале приведите в порядок код. У Вас от этого и проблемы. Выделите кусок кода который должен приводить на русскоязычный сайт и оформите его отдельным блоком. То есть ВСЕ случаи ведущие на русскоязычный сайт.

Comment: Согласен с @teran - если вам важно куда будут переходить роботы, то перенесите их проверку в самое начало и переводите их на нужные вам версии сайта.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Здравствуйте, пробовал, ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный код определяет является ли запрос от бота и сохраняет результат в переменную **$isBot** и затем выполняет ваш код:

```
<?php
    
    require_once('config.php'); 
    
      $user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
      $options = [
        'YandexBot', 'YandexAccessibilityBot', 'YandexMobileBot','YandexDirectDyn',
        'YandexScreenshotBot', 'YandexImages', 'YandexVideo', 'YandexVideoParser',
        'YandexMedia', 'YandexBlogs', 'YandexFavicons', 'YandexWebmaster',
        'YandexPagechecker', 'YandexImageResizer','YandexAdNet', 'YandexDirect',
        'YaDirectFetcher', 'YandexCalendar', 'YandexSitelinks', 'YandexMetrika',
        'YandexNews', 'YandexNewslinks', 'YandexCatalog', 'YandexAntivirus',
        'YandexMarket', 'YandexVertis', 'YandexForDomain', 'YandexSpravBot',
        'YandexSearchShop', 'YandexMedianaBot', 'YandexOntoDB', 'YandexOntoDBAPI',
        'Googlebot', 'Googlebot-Image', 'Mediapartners-Google', 'AdsBot-Google',
        'Mail.RU_Bot', 'bingbot', 'Accoona', 'ia_archiver', 'Ask Jeeves',
        'OmniExplorer_Bot', 'W3C_Validator', 'WebAlta', 'YahooFeedSeeker', 'Yahoo!',
        'Ezooms', '', 'Tourlentabot', 'MJ12bot', 'AhrefsBot', 'SearchBot', 'SiteStatus',
        'Nigma.ru', 'Baiduspider', 'Statsbot', 'SISTRIX', 'AcoonBot', 'findlinks',
        'proximic', 'OpenindexSpider','statdom.ru', 'Exabot', 'Spider', 'SeznamBot',
        'oBot', 'C-T bot', 'Updownerbot', 'Snoopy', 'heritrix', 'Yeti',
        'DomainVader', 'DCPbot', 'PaperLiBot'
      ];
      foreach($options as $option)
      {
          if(!empty($option)){
        if(strpos($user_agent, $option) == true){
            $isBot = true;
            break;
        }else{
            $isBot = false;
        }
    }
        
      }
        
      if(!$isBot){
          
        $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
        $geoplugin->locate();
   
        $var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
        if ($var_country_code == "RU") {
            header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
        }
        else if ($var_country_code == "US") {
            header('Location: https://www.site.ru/en/');
        }
        else if ($var_country_code == "UA") {
            header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
        }
        else if ($var_country_code == "KG") {
            header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
        }
        else if ($var_country_code == "UZ") {
            header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
        }
        else {
        header('Location: https://www.site.ru/en/');
        }
    }
    else{
        header('Location: https://www.site.ru/ru/');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, ваш код полон и отлично работает. Система даст мне возможность перевести балы через 22 часа. Я обязательно завтра переведу! С уважением!

Comment: @Arcadiy, рад что смог помочь!

Comment: а нельзя там типа `$lang = ['RU' => 'ru', ....]; $url = "http://example.com/" . $lang[$code] ?? 'en'` вместо кучи ифов? и `$isBot  = strpos(...) >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы хотите реализовать называется [клоакинг](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/threats/cloaking.html?lang=ru) и жестко наказывается поисковиками. Для того чтобы просигнализировать поисковикам о наличии языковой версии сайта воспользуйтесь [справкой](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?hl=ru).

Comment: Я интересовался об этому Техподдепжки Яндекса, они ответили что если переадресация внутри сайта, никаких фильтров не будет. Я им привел в пример свой сайт, они ответили, санкций не будет  их стороны. Так же на каждой языковой версии стоит lang="ru" или lang="en", прописан каноникал. Переадресация главной на языковую версию идет по 302 коду, так же у пользователя есть возможность в ручном режиме переключить на нужный язык на сайте

Comment: https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/threats/cloaking.html?lang=ru  Цитата из вашей ссылки -  `вопрос: "Мой сайт умеет определять, из какого региона пришел посетитель, и показывать соответствующий контент. Это клоакинг?"  - ответ Яндекса "В данном случае, как и в предыдущем, отсутствует попытка обмана. Так что клоакингом это считаться не будет."   Об этом даже в вашей ссылке написано

Comment: "Возможно ли как то написать условие через ЮзерАгент чтоб робот Гугла и Яндекса всегда получали русскую версию сайта" - отдача пользователю одного контента, а поисковику другого это клоакинг

Comment: Алексей, проблема в том, что Яндекс мне писал, что у них роботы не все имеют российские IP и если с иностранного IP зайдет их робот, то заместо русской версии сайта будет проиндексирована английская, а гугла всегда американский ip, так как сайт в основном русскоязычный, то и роботам должна быть видна только русская версия сайта. Яндекс писал, что роботам их должен отдаваться один и тот же контент. Сайт у нас поисковик авиабилетов, мультиязычный, какой может быть клоакинг когда пользоватлю отдается тот контент, который нужен.

Comment: Платон Яндексович часто отвечает формально. Сомневаюсь что вы задавали им вопрос "Будет ли являться клоакингом отдача разного контента пользователю и роботу?"

Comment: контент один и тот же.

Comment: Почитайте, сейчас задал вопрос Яндексу, что они ответили и прокомментируйте это здесь https://cloud.mail.ru/public/kspw/Qg3NwVzKF

Comment: Если вы будете редиректить поисковики на русскую версию, то индексироваться будет она, но тогда зачем вам мультиязычность, если  страниц на иных языках не будет в поиске и ваш сайт никто не найдет ? :) Задумайтесь! Эту ли цель вы преследуете?

Comment: Сайт очень хорошо ранжируются по Москве и Санкт-Петербургу, по нашей статистике, 18% пользователей иностранцы, находящиеся на территории Москвовской и Ленинградской области, они зайдя на сайт переключают его на английский язык, для этого есть выбор и мультиязычность

Comment: вот вы сами себе и ответили, что зарубежом с иностранных IP сайт не ранжируется и своими действиями вы этому способствуете :)

Comment: В данном случае это за клоакинг не считается. Это всего-лишь локализация сайта, и, что на английском языке, что на другом контент будет один и тотже. Мы всего-лишь меняем языка текста отдаваемый боту

Comment: Контент отличающийся языком - это другой контент. Чтобы маркировать контент на другом языке призван специальный заголовок Content Language https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3282

Answer (score -2):

Вот работающий код

```
    <?php

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $options = array(
        'YandexBot', 'YandexAccessibilityBot', 'YandexMobileBot','YandexDirectDyn',
        'YandexScreenshotBot', 'YandexImages', 'YandexVideo', 'YandexVideoParser',
        'YandexMedia', 'YandexBlogs', 'YandexFavicons', 'YandexWebmaster',
        'YandexPagechecker', 'YandexImageResizer','YandexAdNet', 'YandexDirect',
        'YaDirectFetcher', 'YandexCalendar', 'YandexSitelinks', 'YandexMetrika',
        'YandexNews', 'YandexNewslinks', 'YandexCatalog', 'YandexAntivirus',
        'YandexMarket', 'YandexVertis', 'YandexForDomain', 'YandexSpravBot',
        'YandexSearchShop', 'YandexMedianaBot', 'YandexOntoDB', 'YandexOntoDBAPI',
        'Googlebot', 'Googlebot-Image', 'Mediapartners-Google', 'AdsBot-Google',
        'Mail.RU_Bot', 'bingbot', 'Accoona', 'ia_archiver', 'Ask Jeeves',
        'OmniExplorer_Bot', 'W3C_Validator', 'WebAlta', 'YahooFeedSeeker', 'Yahoo!',
        'Ezooms', '', 'Tourlentabot', 'MJ12bot', 'AhrefsBot', 'SearchBot', 'SiteStatus',
        'Nigma.ru', 'Baiduspider', 'Statsbot', 'SISTRIX', 'AcoonBot', 'findlinks',
        'proximic', 'OpenindexSpider','statdom.ru', 'Exabot', 'Spider', 'SeznamBot',
        'oBot', 'C-T bot', 'Updownerbot', 'Snoopy', 'heritrix', 'Yeti',
        'DomainVader', 'DCPbot', 'PaperLiBot'
    );
    if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $options)) {
        header('Location: https://www.yandex.ru/');
        return;
    }
}

header('Location: https://google.com');
```

Заменяйте последнюю линию на ваш код для гео-проверки и перенаправлений, а https://www.yandex.ru на нужный вам адрес.

Comment: @Danial Protopopov Непонятен Ваш комментарий к ответу, с уважением